# Filtering a subform in Microsoft Access using an unbound textbox in main form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two forms: "**Job Sheet**" (the main form) and "**Jobs sub**" (the subform).

I'm trying to use the '*afterupdate*' function with an unbound textbox called **yrcheck** to filter the datasheet view of the subform, by the **JbYr** field.

Please tell me, what's wrong with this code?

```
Private Sub yrcheck_AfterUpdate()

Dim yr As Integer
yr = Me.yrcheck
[Jobs sub].Form.Filter "JbYr='" & yr & "'"
[Jobs sub].Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

I get "Invalid Use of Property" as an error.

What's wrong?

Comment: What is JbYr? a string, number or date?

Comment: JbYr is a 'long integer', number type field.

Comment: I figured yr should be integer, but when I try to do so the error doesn't let up.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to tell us which line triggers the error.  Since you did not, I'll guess this line is the culprit ...

```vb
[Jobs sub].Form.Filter "JbYr='" & yr & "'"
```

If my guess is correct, include an `=` sign between `Filter` and the string expression ...

```vb
[Jobs sub].Form.Filter = "JbYr='" & yr & "'"
                       ^
                      here
```

If the datatype of that `JbYr` field is numeric, eliminate the single quotes before and after the value of `yr` ...

```vb
[Jobs sub].Form.Filter = "JbYr=" & yr
```

I would also reference the subform control via `Me`, similar to @Smandoli's suggestion, but I don't think that was the source of your original error ...

```vb
Me![Jobs sub].Form.Filter = "JbYr=" & yr
```

Comment: Hey Hans, thank you for your reply. I've tried a combination of everyone's solutions and the errors either persist, or nothing at all happens. 

To clear up confusion, I stored the filter itself as a string.

This is my new code: 
`
Private Sub yrcheck_AfterUpdate()

    Dim yr As Integer
    Dim strFilter As String
    strFilter = "JbYr= " & yr & ""
    yr = Me.yrcheck
    Me![Jobs sub].Filter = strFilter
    Me![Jobs sub].FilterOn = True

End Sub
`
___ 

I Have used the equal sign, removed the equal sign, used the single quotes, removed the single quotes, and the error persists. I'm lost.

Comment: Tried it, without the Me! before the [Jobs sub]. 

When I run it, the same error occurs, but the line that is below, `Me![Jobs sub].FilterOn = True`, is the one that flags an error. Removed the Me! before that line, and then I get a different kind of error and the entire method declaration flags an error.

Comment: Please note when I copy and paste Smandoli's code, it does not yield an error and it doesn't yield results either. Nothing happens, no filter turns on.

Comment: I wish I could, however the database is for my office and has confidential information on it, apparently, so I didn't get the permission to :( Thank you, I figured nothing much was wrong with the code.

Comment: I wish I could explain this and have it understood.... Actually the safest thing for me to do is make a 'mock' copy of the database, try the code there and see if it works, and if it doesn't, send that to you? Please hold.

Comment: Also, thank you very very much for your help and patience.

Comment: Okay this is what I discovered - the database is split into two. There is the database that holds the forms, and one that holds the actual table structure and data. I could send you the one with the forms alone but obviously you can't access the data with that alone. Can you give me advice on a quick way to join both files into one that I can bundle up, clear out sensitive data and send that for you instead?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is in the way you reference the subform.  Try:

```
Private Sub yrcheck_AfterUpdate()

    Dim yr As Integer
    yr = Me.yrcheck
    Me![Jobs sub].Filter "JbYr='" & yr & "'"
    Me![Jobs sub].FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying this and no error occurs, but nothing happens (sorry, the error does NOT persist as I previously typed). Literally copied and pasted your code.

Comment: Note: I have removed the single quotes IRT someone else's advice. Then the error occured again. Put the single quotes back, and the error still occurs and won't stop occuring. D:

Answer (score 0):

A non-code solution is to leave this filter and just include the textbox in the masterfields and expand the childfields:

```
[Id],[yrcheck]
[ParentID],[JbYr]
```

This will also remove the option for the user to remove this filter.

Comment: I thought I commented to you before, but it didn't seem to send, I'm sorry. I would need the users to be able to remove the filter to view all records, and re-filter in that one manner, as they need.